# Image engine , How to access images in my pages in views

Tags: refinerycms

For  refinerycms , I added the engine which contain the image as field.
When i added image it will be in under Images tab of refinery admin.

How to access that images , in my views files ?

Using Refinery 2.0.2 .

I found this :

```
{ 
<% Image.all.each do |image| %>
  <%= image_fu image, "100x100", :id => dom_id(image) %>
<% end %>
}
```

The error i got is ,

> NameError in Refinery/pages#show
>   uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Image.

I added the pages manually and assign the template for each. (admin page , under pages tab)
So in one page I want to access the Engine model which contain image field.
I get access of all other data but image i am not able to access.

Answer (score 0):

Think you're over complicating things.
Firstly, assuming the view you're talking about the engine's 'show view' (i.e in refinery 2.x vendor/extension/ext_name/app/views/refinery/ext_names/ext_names/show).
if so the view code should already be generated to render the image (assuming you called the field photo).

i.e 
    <%= image_fu @ext_name.photo, "350x225" %>

If however you want to see image generated on something other than this show view, then you're also have to make sure the resource is available to the view (i.e add the @ext_name retrieval to the respective controller).

Also, the images admin tab is like a view into a bucket for all images associated to the refinery install - i would ignore this exists - you need to add the image within the engine/extension admin tab.

Answer (score 0):

If you want thumbnails listed in your engine page's index.html.erb:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
<%= image_tag(product.image.thumbnail('100x100>').url) %>
<% end %>
```

where "products" is your engine's name.

Answer (score 0):

With the refinery-cms-page-images gem installed, every page has access to an images association:

```
<%- @page.images.each do |image| -%>
  <%= image_tag image.thumbnail('60x60').url %>
<%- end -%>
```

That's all you need!